# looping through the rows of a matrix in sage

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, sage

I am trying to program a Graham-Schmidt process in sage and cannot figure out how to loop through the rows of an array.

```
def graham_schmidt(W):
    a=0
    U=W 
    for i in W.dims()[0]:# this is the not working part
        print w
        a=a+1
        for j in xrange(0,-2):
            a=a+1
            U[i]=U[i]-(transpose(U[j])*w)/(transpose(U[j])*U[j])*U[j]
    return a;
```

Comment: What is the type of `W`? Did you try this one: `for i in W.dims()[0]`? Where does variable `w` get a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're making things far too complicated. If `W` is not a sparse matrix, you can just do

```
for row in W:
```

Since you also need the row index, you can use Python's built-in `enumerate`:

```
for i, row in enumerate(W):
```

or (uglier)

```
for i in xrange(len(W.shape[0])):
```